# 2d Array Sorting in C

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, multidimensional-array

I am trying to sort an 2d array, where I sort by column. but what I have seen online so far is confusing, if I could have an example explained in detail that would help a lot! so far I have tried (bubble) and selection sort, either one of these would be fine but I cannot seem to get them to work.

I was working with this code but when I try to execute there is no output. I can get the first function to give an output, but I cannot even get the "working so far" to print. please let me know if you have any ideas.

```
   //declare libraries
  
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
  
   //declare other functions/files to be used in the program
   void print_fun(void);
   int sort_fun(int arg, unsigned char networks[arg][4]);
   void read_fun(void);
 
 
  //read command line input and store the information
  int main(int argc, char** argv){
      //declar variable
      int arg = 0;
 
      //make argv into an int
      arg = atoi(argv[1]);
      //assign size to networks
       unsigned char networks[arg][4];
 
      //assign input to networks
      for (int j =0; j<1; ++j){
          if(argc == 1)
               {
                  printf("ERROR ERROR, you messed up\n");
              }
 
          else
          {
          // hold network addresses in a 2-d array, with 4 unsigned char
 
              for(int k = 0; k<arg; k++){
                  for (int i =0; i<4; i++){
 
                  scanf("%hhu.", &networks[k][i]);
                  //checks to see if scanf was working properly
                 // printf(" %hhu",networks[k][i]);
 
              }
                  //printf("\n");
              }}}
 
 
  //sort array
 
  //count networks
 
  //print info about the array
 
  }
  int sort_fun(int arg, unsigned char networks[arg][4]){
      //declaring variabes
      printf("working so far?");
  //sorting by comlumn p
      for (int k = 0; k < arg; k++){
          for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
              for (int j = i+1; j<4; ++j){
                  if (networks[k][i] > networks[k][j]) {
                      int swap = networks[k][i];
                      networks[k][i] = networks[k][j];
                      networks[k][j] = swap;
                  }
         }
         //printf("%hhu +++++",networks[k][i]);
          }
      }
  return(0);
  }
```

Comment: Please remove line numbers from code: easier to compile.

Comment: Your `main` routine does not call `sort_fun`, nor does anything else, so of course the code in `sort_fun` never gets executed, including the statement `printf("working so far?");`.

Comment: do i call for it by placing sort_fun(); in main?

Comment: Sample input is missing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [2d Array Sorting by Column in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67655322/2d-array-sorting-by-column-in-c)